# ggplot is showing every value instead of groups

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have a text file that is quite simple where `is_MI` is a dummy variable.

```
is_MI blood_pressure
0     123
0     222
0     111
1     333
1     123
```

However, when I try to plot this code through a histogram or boxplot

`ggplot(df_sbp) + geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = is_MI))`

Instead of having two bars, one for 0 and 1 each, it's listing out every single data point like [image: so].

I've tried every combination of things for `ggplot`, but can't seem to work this out. I've also tried `factor(is_MI)`.

Here is the output for `dput(droplevels(df_sbp[1:20, ]))` as suggested by the comments.

```
structure(
      list(
        is_MI = structure(
          c(9L, 9L, 7L, 1L, 8L, 17L, 12L, 18L, 5L, 14L, 3L, 11L, 15L, 16L, 4L, 2L, 10L, 6L, 13L, 9L),
          .Label = c("0 89","0 93", "0 95", "0  98", "0 100", "0 105", "0 109",
                     "0 114", "0 116", "0 126", "0 128", "0 129", "0 130",
                     "0 132", "0 136", "0 141", "0 146", "0 157"), 
          class = "factor"),
        blood_pressure = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                          NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), 
      row.names = c(NA, 20L), 
    class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: are you sure that `is_MI` only contains 0 and 1's? try `round(is_MI)`

Comment: Your problem is that your x-axis is a factor and has lots of different levels. If you think it's a dummy variable, look at `table(df_sbp$is_MI)` to see what's actually there.

Comment: Can you post the output of `dput(df_sbp)` in your question?

Comment: `dput(df_sbp)` will be way too long with all those factor levels! Post `dput(droplevels(df_sbp[1:20, ]))`

Comment: @Gregor I've added the output for `dput(droplevels(df_sbp[1:20, ]))`

Comment: From the output you can see that the data is not read in properly as the values for blood_pressure are NA wheras the values of is_MI are characters....In future please don't add output as a picture, but copy and paste it into your questions to make it more reproducible.

Comment: @Z.Lin I've added the output for `dput(droplevels(df_sbp[1:20, ]))`

Comment: No image, please. Please paste the output of `dput`.

Comment: The question is not very clear on what your desired output is.  A barplot of count of is_MT, a histograms of bp vs is_MT, or a boxplot (bp~is_MT)

Comment: @DavidBang for next time, paste the *text* of `dput` into your question. `dput` is great because if you give me the dput text, I can paste it into my R session and get a copy of your data. But I can't paste an image into R.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your data, that somewhere in your code is_MI and blood_pressure concatanated. I.e. instead two separatate numbers`0` and `116` you have got a space separated string `"0 116"` in `is_MI` and `NA` in `blood_pressure`. So here is the effect you are observing, viz. instead of 2 columns you see a lot of character strings transformed to factor.

Please see the code below, where `strplit` function used to extract numbers from your string. I inttentionally included several `1`'s into data, as your `head` contains only `0`'s.

```
df <- structure(
  list(
    is_MI = structure(
      c(9L, 9L, 7L, 1L, 8L, 17L, 12L, 18L, 5L, 14L, 3L, 11L, 15L, 16L, 4L, 2L, 10L, 6L, 13L, 9L),
      .Label = c("0 89","0 93", "0 95", "0  98", "0 100", "0 105", "0 109",
                 "0 114", "0 116", "0 126", "0 128", "0 129", "0 130",
                 "0 132", "0 136", "0 141", "0 146", "0 157"), 
      class = "factor"),
    blood_pressure = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                      NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), 
  row.names = c(NA, 20L), 
class = "data.frame") 


x <- paste(df$is_MI, sep = " ", collapse = " ")
y <- na.omit(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(x, " "))))
z <- data.frame(matrix(y, byrow = TRUE, ncol = 2))
names(z) <- c("is_MI", "blood_pressure")
z[1, 1] <- 1
z[14, 1] <- 1

ggplot(z) + geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = is_MI))
```

Output:
[image: graph]